# Proof by contradiction: finding integers that satisfy $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, integers

Assume for contradiction $\exists a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$.

My current idea for finding a contradiction is to square each side, isolate the square-rooted terms, and repeat. This is pretty cumbersome and therefore I'm wondering if there's an easier way to proving no such integers exist. Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You only have to square it once - see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write it as
$b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}-a
$.

Squaring, this becomes
$2b^2+2bc\sqrt{6}+3c^2
=6-2a\sqrt{6}+a^2
$
or
$(2bc+2a)\sqrt{6}
=6-2b^2-3c^2+a^2
$.

Since $\sqrt{6}$
is irrational,
this can only hold if
$bc+a = 0$
and
$6-2b^2-3c^2+a^2
= 0
$.

Since $a = -bc$,
the original equation becomes
$-bc+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}
$
or
$0
=\sqrt{6}-b\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}+bc
=(\sqrt{2}-c)(\sqrt{3}-b)
$.

But this implies that
either $c = \sqrt{2}$
or
$b = \sqrt{3}$,
which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The lemma below implies that $\,1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6\:$ are linearly independendent over $\,\Bbb Q.$

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ [K(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}) : K] = 4\ $ if  $\rm\ \sqrt{a},\ \sqrt{b},\ \sqrt{a\:b}\, $ are all $\rm\,\not\in K,\:$ and $\rm\: 2 \ne 0\:$ in $\rm\,K.$

**Proof** $\ \ $  Let  $\rm\ L = K(\sqrt{b})\:.\:$ Then $\rm\:  [L:K] = 2\:$  via  $\rm\:\sqrt{b}  \not\in K,\:$  thus it suffices to show $\rm\: [L(\sqrt{a}):L] = 2\:.\:$ It fails only if  $\rm\:\sqrt{a} \in L = K(\sqrt{b})\ $ and then $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\  r + s\ \sqrt{b}\ $  for $\rm\ r,s\in K.\:$ But that's impossible, since squaring yields $\rm(1):\ \ a\ =\ r^2 + b\ s^2 + 2\:r\:s\  \sqrt{b}\:,\: $  contra, hypotheses, as follows

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad rs \ne 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{b}\ \in\  K\ \ $ by solving $(1)$ for $\rm\sqrt{b}\:,\:$ using  $\rm\:2 \ne 0$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\  s = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \ \sqrt{a}\ \in\  K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ r \in K$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\  r = 0\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sqrt{a\:b}\in K\ \ $  via  $\rm\ \sqrt{a}\ =\ s\ \sqrt{b}\:,\: \ $times $\rm\:\sqrt{b}\quad$ **QED**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first show that if $a+b\sqrt{2}=c+d\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a=c,b=d$. 
Suppose $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$, so $(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=3(c-\sqrt{2})^2$. Then you can set up equations relating $a,b,c$ and try to get  a contradiction. Since $ab=-3$, there are not many possible cases to try.