# There are no rational $a, b, c $ with $a+b\sqrt{u}+c\sqrt{v} =\sqrt{uv} $

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers

If $u$ and  $v$
are rationals such that
 $\sqrt{u}, \sqrt{v}, $ and $\sqrt{uv}$
are all irrational,
show that there are no
rational $a, b, $ and $c$
such that
$a+b\sqrt{u}+c\sqrt{v}
=\sqrt{uv}
$.

This is a generalization
of my answer 
to this question:

[Proof by contradiction: finding integers that satisfy $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032239/proof-by-contradiction-finding-integers-that-satisfy-ab-sqrt2c-sqrt3-sq/2032256)

I will post a solution
in two days
if there are 
no posted solutions.

Comment: I don't see what are you looking for: a simpler proof? That's because you can take exactly the one you posted with $u,v$ replacing $2,3$.

Comment: That is what I did. But I thought that this generalization was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$a+b\sqrt{u}+c\sqrt{v} +\sqrt{uv}=(\sqrt u+c)(\sqrt v+b)+(a-bc).$$
Now if there is a $t\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\sqrt u+c=t$ and  $\sqrt v+b=\dfrac{bc-a}{t},$ then  $\sqrt u,\sqrt v\in\Bbb{Q}$ which contradicts to your assumption.
Hence $(\sqrt u+c)(\sqrt v+b)\notin\Bbb{Q}\,\,\,\,\,\forall b,c\in\Bbb{Q}.$
[There is a very nice generalization of this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956747/linear-independence-of-fractional-powers).

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:**  $\sqrt{u}$ and $\sqrt{v}$ must be linearly independent over the rationals.

Else $a \sqrt{u} + b \sqrt{v} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ $\implies$ $(a \sqrt{u} + b \sqrt{v})^2 = a^2 u + b^2 v + 2ab \sqrt{uv} \in \mathbb{Q}$ $\implies$ $\sqrt{uv} \in \mathbb{Q}$, contrary to the hypothesis.

**Proof:**

$$
\sqrt{uv}=a+b\sqrt{u}+c\sqrt{v} \quad\quad \Big| \cdot \sqrt{u}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
u \sqrt{v} & =a\sqrt{u}+bu+c\sqrt{uv} \\
 & = a\sqrt{u}+bu+c(a+b\sqrt{u}+c\sqrt{v}) \\
 & = (a+bc)\sqrt{u} + c^2 \sqrt{v} + ac + bu
\end{align}
$$

By the linear independence proved in the lemma, the coefficients of $\sqrt{v}$ must match i.e. $\,u = c^2\,$ but that contradicts the irrationality of $\sqrt{u}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a proof (without looking at yours).

Suppose there's some such combination. Square both sides to get an expression involving $\sqrt{uv}$. Isolate that term to get an expression of $\sqrt{uv}$ as a rational combination of $\sqrt{u}$, $\sqrt{v}$ and $1$.

Set this equal to the supposed expression for $\sqrt{uv}$ that you started with, and move everything to one side. You end up with a rational combination of $1, \sqrt{u}, \sqrt{v}$ that's zero. Write this in the form
$$
A = B \sqrt{u} + C\sqrt{v}
$$
and square it to get
$$
A^2 = B^2 u + C^2 v + 2BC \sqrt{uv}
$$
from which we see that $\sqrt{uv}$ is written as a linear combination of rationals, which is a contradiction.

Yeah, you have to worry about various coefficients not being zero. That's why I said it was a sketch. :)

Comment: Fill in the details and I might accept.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r = \sqrt{u}, s = \sqrt{v}\implies a + br + cs = rs\implies s = \dfrac{a+br}{r-c}\implies s^2 \in \mathbb{Q}\implies r \in \mathbb{Q}$ since $r^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, contradiction to $r \in \mathbb{Q^c}$. Thus there are no $a,b,c$ which "satisfies" the given condition.

Comment: Where have you used the part of the hypothesis that says $\sqrt{uv}$ is irrational?

Comment: The proof I employed does not require the use of the information that you pointed out.

Comment: Good catch. Working out the algebra, I get that $s^2(r^2+c^2)-a^2-b^2r^2 = 2r(ab+cs^2)$ so that $ab+cs^2=0$ and $s^2(r^2+c^2)-a^2-b^2r^2=0$ which looks harder than my original proof.

Comment: @DeepSea Without that condition $2+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{4}$.